# Google Map API : Marker within marked polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon, marker

I have nearly 4 to 5 thousand markers plotted on the map. I want user to allow to draw a polygon on the map and then delete those markers which are within the shaded polygon. Can anyone please guide me on how to find which markers are within the shaded area of polygon ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you'll need to use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry). Append `libraries=geometry` to the query string of the URL you use for loading the Maps API:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Then you can use the [containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation) function to check if each marker is inside the polygon.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(markers[i].getPosition(), yourPolygon)) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming here you've got these 5k markers in an array called `markers`.  And by 'delete those markers' you simply mean remove them from the view.  You'd perhaps also want to fire off an ajax request at this point, and/or remove them from that markers array.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Actually I wanted to capture the remaining markers the user i.e deleting the markers for the given user so that next time when he loads the map, he will not be able to see the earlier deleted markers.

Comment: Are your users logged in, so you're storing those markers server-side against their profile?  Or using client-side storage like a cookie or [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: I want to store them them @server side. And I have to allow user to draw one by one multiple polygon and delete the markers in the shaded area of polygon. Are you suggesting that instead of deleting them at client side send the drawn polygon co-ordinates to the sever and mark them as deleted for that user & resend the remaining markers. Will it not consumer too much client-server traffic ?

Comment: No, I'd say do it all client-side for removing the markers, and send ajax requests just indicating which markers you're removing for that user. Either within the loop for every marker, or get the user to click a button to send them all in one request